# How to cool down a T100TA tablet PC?

Tags: cooling, tablet

I bought an Asus T100TA tablet PC and I use it quite a lot (mostly for watching movies and browsing). CPU usage is between 25%-75% for several hours every day and it heats up quite a bit.

Is there anything I can do to lower the temperature? Would MacGyver-ing a small radiator on the outer surface help dissipate the heat or make things worse?

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure the firmware is up to date. Power management updates can sometimes marginally affect the thermal profile of a product. Attaching a radiator... The problem there is that the case is plastic. Ideally it would be metal. You can still attach a heatsink if you like, but I wouldn't expect miracles from it. If you're going to do that, use thermal paste in the center, and attach it via epoxy or whatever other means you desire at the sides. WARNING: This will likely result in cosmetic damage to the case if you ever want to remove it. Depending on how strong the bond is, it may even tear a hole in it, and there's no telling what that could do to the internals.